# How to set a default value in Knex migration?

Tags: knex.js

I would like to set a default value for a primary key in a Knex migration, but I'm running into issues. This is my initial migration:

```
exports.up = (knex, Promise) => {
  return knex.schema.createTable(
    'users',
    (table) => {
      table.uuid('id').primary();
      table.string('email');
    }
  );
};
```

I would like to default the `id` field to a random UUID. So this is my next migration:

```
exports.up = (knex, Promise) => {
  return Promise.all([
    knex.raw('create extension if not exists "uuid-ossp"'),
    knex.schema.alterTable('users', (table) => {
      table.uuid('id')
        .defaultTo(knex.raw('uuid_generate_v4()'))
        .alter();
    }),
  ]);
};
```

When I run that I get the following error:

```
migration failed with error: alter table "users" alter column "id" drop not null - column "id" is in a primary key
```

Based on that it looks like Knex is trying to drop the `NOT NULL` constraint. I tried chaining a `.notNullable()` before the `.defaultTo()` and it still gives the same error. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is a quick copy/paste answer for those who came here searching "How to set a default value in Knex migration"

```
table.string('state').notNullable().defaultTo('pending')
```

Note: `notNullable()` is not required.

Comment: This will single quote whatever value you pass to `defaultTo()`, e.g. `table.uuid('foo').defaultTo('uuid_generate_v4()');` will result in `"foo" uuid default 'uuid_generate_v4()'` which will result in an error: "invalid input syntax for type uuid"

Comment: @luukvhoudt by using .defaultTo('uuid_generate_v4()') you are setting **UUID** named **foo** to have default value of a **string** 'uuid_generate_v4()' and this is not valid uuid. To set default uuid value in Knex.js try the following: ```table.uuid('foo').defaultTo(knex.raw('UUID()'))```

Answer (score 0):

You need to drop the primary key, alter the column, and then recreate it.